# Is there a way to highlight a specific set of words in TinyMCE editor?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using **TinyMCE** editor in my Angular project . I'm looking for a way to highlight words in TinyMCE editor if they are part of an array .

Example,

```
countries: string[] = ['india', 'england', 'argentina'];
```

If user types any of the item from above array , I want to highlight them in bold font . Let's say user types the below line . Only the items that are part of the array are made bold .

> Some countries are **india** , bangladesh , **argentina** and **england** .

Kindly let me know if there is a way to achieve this . Thanks in advance.

Here is the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tinymce-2ywvce?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) link